# View what methods/functions return a specific object in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, api

I'm making a C# application in Visual Studio and am wondering if there is any way to view every method that returns a specific type?

For example, I want to know which methods return an "AsymmetricAlgorithm" object.

Comment: You mean, returns a specific type, right? An object is an instance of a type.

Comment: @John, read past the subject.  He was perfectly clear in the question itself by using the same terms that you did.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) shows this (and is free); just View => Search (or <kbd>F3</kbd>) to find the type, then Tools => Analyze (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>), and expand Exposed By in the Analyzer panel.

Answer (score 2):

Buy JetBrains resharper. It has features that do that (its called "find usages") and looooads of others. (no I dont work there).

Comment: If your project is open source it is free to use.