# Class usage details from class structure

Tags: c#, asp.net, class

I have a question regarding the `Membership` and `MembershipUser` classes in System.Web.Security Namespace.

Both these classes are present in separate Libraries, how would someone know the usage details without going through any documentation and just by the class methods, properties etc? If I come across `MembershipUser` class I would know there is  an `Email` property which I can get and set, but I wouldn't know there exists a `Membership` class which has method returning user details as `MembershipUser` return type without somehow coming across it.

For e.g. to getting Users Email address we can create a `MembershipUser` object and use the `GetUser()` method provided by `Membership` class as `GetUser()` has the return type of `Membership`. Something like this.

```
MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser();    
string Email = user.Email;
```

MembershipUser Class:

```
public class MembershipUser
{
  ...
  public virtual string Email { get; set; }
  ...
}
```

Membership Class:

```
public static class Membership
{
  ...
  public static MembershipUser GetUser();
  ...
}
```

Comment: What's the real question here?

Comment: Sometimes you just have to read documentation. How would you know either of those classes exists without documentation? How would you even know that the .NET framework exists if it weren't documented somewhere? This question is too meta to be answered.

Comment: Well, if you don't want to read the documentation, you could decompile the assemblies using dotPeek or ILSpy and navigate through the objects. But I am not sure that that is going to save you any effort.It is good to be lazy if you are a developer by automating repetitive tasks, but I don't think that rule applies to doing research.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you may be looking for a "find methods by return type" facility in Visual Studio that allows you to say "which methods in the .net library return this type", or specifically in your example "which methods return an object of type `MembershipUser`"?

To my knowledge VS doesn't have that facility, but the ReSharper extension does.  If you have ReSharper you can right click on a Type and then choose "Find Usages Advanced" and then pick the "Solutions and libraries" option and "Usages" and "Usages of Members":

[image: Resharper Find Usages Advanced Dialog Window]

And hit Find to get a list like this:

[image: RESharper Find Usages search results]

As you can see, that list includes the `GetUser` function in the results.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3240792/1879019) also mentions the [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/) extension as an alternative option for this.

As others have said though, there is no substitute for reading the documentation for libraries you're planning to use.  It's straightforward for a library author to describe how a particular method works (in the code comments that then become visible in intellisense when using that library), but it's often impractical to try and describe how different classes interact in those comments.

Often the different ways pieces will interact aren't known when writing the classes, and indeed well written code will deliberately seek to keep classes well separated so they can be used in new ways later.  Therefore the only practical place for a library author to describe the interaction of the various elements of a library is in its documentation.